# ExtJS 6.0.2 Create a Panel with two nested Panels using hbox layout

Tags: layout, extjs, scroll, panel

I am trying to build a panel with two components using hbox layout, one of fixed width on the left, the second would contain multiple forms side by side and should be horizontally scrollable. I want to keep first component locked in place, while the user scrolls the second component.
I created a parent Panel and nested two panels within it, and added scrollable property to Panel 2 but it doesn't seem to work. Are there any other layouts that would help me achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            width: 1000,
            scrollable: 'x',
            title: "Panel2",
            items: [{
                xtype: "form",
                items: [{
                    layout: "column",
                    items: [{
                        columnWidth: 0.4,
                        layout: "form",
                        title: "1",
                        items: [{
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            fieldLabel: "My Label",
                            name: "textvalue",
                            align: "center",
                            width: 50
                        }, {
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            fieldLabel: "My Label",
                            name: "textvalue",
                            align: "center",
                            width: 50
                        }, {
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            fieldLabel: "My Label",
                            name: "textvalue",
                            align: "center",
                            width: 50
                        }, {
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            fieldLabel: "My Label",
                            name: "textvalue",
                            align: "center",
                            width: 50
                        }]
                    }, {
                        columnWidth: 0.4,
                        layout: "form",
                        title: "2",
                        height: 50,
                        items: [{
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            fieldLabel: "Field 2 Label",
                            name: "textvalue"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        columnWidth: 0.2,
                        layout: "form",
                        title: "3",
                        items: [{
                            xtype: "checkbox",
                            fieldLabel: "Label",
                            boxLabel: "Box label",
                            name: "checkbox",
                            inputValue: "cbvalue"
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });

        var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            width: 250,
            title: "Panel1"
        });

        var parentPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            renderTo: document.body,
            width: 500,
            // scrollable: 'x',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [panel1, panel2]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm made you a working sencha fiddle exmaple: [Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38ju)

What I did different was giving the form the fixed width while the parent panel has a flex value.

- That means panel1 has a fixed width with 250px.
- panel2 has a flex: 1 value and will take the rest of the width available from the parent Container
- When the childs of panel2 (e.g. the forms) that have fixed width are wider than the flexed-width of panel1, the scroller will appear.